# Are Route Handlers in Next.js going to ditch the need for Express.js and co.?

Tags: express, next.js

Creative uses of `route.js` in Next.js 13 look like they could end our need to implement APIs solely for the sake of supporting code running business logic, database manipulation, etc.
In order to allow third-party integrations, we'll probably still need to rely on having to implement APIs, but the Route Handlers might limit their purpose to external use.

What do you think?

Comment: To my knowledge, they are Lambda functions with a cold start and an execution time limit. So depending on what you are doing, you may need an actual API.

Comment: Good point, although, I think that you can deploy server components to a variety of architectures, lambda functions aren't your only option.